# Embedded Parent/Child relation in same class

Tags: java, hibernate, parent-child, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to map a Parent Child relationship within a single table with a composite id.
But I had some difficulties with it and could not seem to find the right answer through Google & Stackoverflow.

Now, while writing this posting, I figured it out! I'm posting this solution as for anyone else who might run into the same "challenge".

**Note:** I left out all the getters and setters to keep it all a bit compact.

First, the table `PlanDBtasktree` as it is (heavily simplified):

```
taskID    mainTaskID      planID
---------------------------------
1         NULL            42
2         1               42
3         1               42
4         2               42
5         2               42
1         NULL            102
```

So the structure would be:

```
1-42
    2-42
        4-42
        5-42
    3-42
1-102
```

taskID & planID is written as `@EmbeddedId`:

```
@Embeddable
public class PlanDBtasktreeID implements Serializable {
  @Basic( optional = false )
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name="planID")
  private PlanDBinstance planID;

  @Basic( optional = false )
  @Column(name = "taskID")
  private Long taskID;
  // equals & hashcode...
}
```

The mapping in the class `PlanDBtasktree`:

```
@EmbeddedId
private PlanDBtasktreeID tId;
```

Now I wanted to retrieve the parent/child relations in this same class, since it's a recursive tree.

The column `mainTaskID` is the "parent" reference. Knowing this I created another `Embeddable` object:

```java
@Embeddable
public class PlanDBmaintreeID implements Serializable {

  @Basic( optional = false )
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name="planID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private PlanDBinstance planID;

  @Basic( optional = false )
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "planID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "maintaskID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  })
  private PlanDBtasktree maintaskID;
}
```

And the mapping for this in the `PlanDBtasktree` class:

```
@Embedded
private PlanDBmaintreeID mtId;
```

And finally, to retrieve the children from `PlanDBtasktree`:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mtId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<PlanDBtasktree> PlanDBtasktree_children_List;
```

The complete mapping for `PlanDBtasktree` class:

```java
public class PlanDBtasktree {
  @EmbeddedId
  private PlanDBtasktreeID tId;

  @Embedded
  private PlanDBmaintreeID mtId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mtId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<PlanDBtasktree> PlanDBtasktree_children_List;
}
```

If someone has some improvements/additions, I'd love to read them.

This has been my first try for solving this, so this probably isn't the cleanest solution.
And this is my first posting here, therefor the formatting could be a bit iffy due to lack of experience :-)